# General solution to $\nabla^2(\nabla^2 -\xi^{-2})\omega = 0$

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-functions

In the paper [here](http://vonkarman.mae.ufl.edu/~peterzhang/hayakawa2000.pdf), the authors present the equation

\begin{align}
\nabla^2(\nabla^2 -\xi^{-2})\omega = 0
\end{align}

where $\xi$ is a constant and $\omega(r,\theta)$ is the variable of interest. This is equation (79) in the paper. In equation (82) they report

\begin{align}
\nabla^2\omega(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n K_n \left(\dfrac{r}{\xi}\right) \sin(n\theta) 
\end{align}

where $C_n$ is a constant and $K_n$ is the modified bessel function. They report the general form of $\omega$ as

\begin{align}
\omega(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ a_{\omega,n}r^n+b_{\omega,n}r^{-n} + C_n\xi^rK_n \left(\dfrac{r}{\xi} \right) \right] \sin(n\theta)
\end{align}

I am trying to reproduce their results and am unsure how they were able to determine this solution. If anyone could direct me towards any resources that discuss this type of equation that would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: You could start by taking $u = \nabla^2 \omega$ then the first equation reads $\nabla^2 u -\xi^{-2}u = 0$ which can be solved to get $u$ then solve for $\nabla^2\omega = u$ to get $\omega$. [btw the link provided does not work]

Comment: @Winther Thanks for the response, the link has been fixed. Is there a reference you could recommend that discusses the general solution to $\nabla^2 u - \xi^{-2}u = 0$?

Comment: I don't know if this is the best approach, I only suggested it since I though this PDE would be more familiar (it's known as Yukawa equation; don't have a good ref. right now). Anyway you can use the good-old [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) to solve it.